# Loan calculation with percentage

Tags: loans, banking, calculation

I want to know monthly payment with percentage. Let's say I took loan of $200 and I have to pay monthly for 5 months and amount pay back is $260. Over here $60 is interest. I could make out that I have to pay $52 each month to make $260 at the end of 5 months. Kindly help to calculate percentage

Comment: Is this homework of some sort? What do you need to express as a percentage of what, and what do you need that number FOR?

Comment: If I understand your payment schedule correctly, it corresponds to an effective annual interest rate of about 195 %. Quite usurious, that.

Comment: No, charging that kind of interest is not in any way, sort, or manner "friendly".

Comment: it might actually be illegal, depending on where you live

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loan equation is

```
s = (d - d (1 + r)^-n)/r
```

where

```
s = principal
n = number of periods
d = periodic payment

s = 200
n = 5
d = 260/n

∴ r = 0.0943489 per period

12 r = 1.13219
```

So the APR is 113% nominal, compounded monthly.

The effective annual rate is 195%.

```
(1 + 0.0943489)^12 - 1 = 1.95032
```

Plot or solver is required to obtain `r`.

[image]